# $P$: $((p \land q) \vee r)\implies (l \vee t)$... If $p$,$q$,and $l$ are all false and $r$ and $t$ are true determine if $P$ is true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> $P$: $((p \land q) \vee r)\implies (l \vee t)$... If $p$,$q$,and $l$ are all false and $r$ and $t$ are true determine if $P$ is true.

How would I show this just by logically writing out $p$ and $q$ false or $r$ true implies $l$ false or $t$ true so $P$ is true? Or would I have to make a truth table which would be complicated. $P$ is true right?

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: Its not a title, if I just have the second part you would not know what the problem was and visa versa.

Comment: Exactly. I just look at the question (I just don't read "titles" once I open the question) and I can't make head or tails with what it is. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well I don't know what type of problem it is to call it anything different, and the way I look at filling out the boxes is question on the top box and then any addition thoughts I have on solving it or questions i have about it.

Comment: In fact when you go to post a question, the spot for title says what is the question?

Comment: OK, maybe that should be reformulated. I'll help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a truth table is one way to prove it. If you don't want to do it you can argue as follows.

Whenever the consequent of a conditional statement is true, the conditional statement is true. Since $t$ is true, so is $l\lor t$, therefore $P$ is true.

Comment: I would have to use that same logic for the other side where p and q false or r true also right?

Comment: The LHS of $\implies$ doesn't matter, that's the whole point of the remark "Whenever the consequent of a conditional statement is true, the conditional statement is true". A conditional statement is false only if the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. So if the consequent is true, necessarily the conditional statement is true. Is it clearer?

Comment: Ok so say the whole thing was $ a \implies b$ the only time that the proposition is false is where a is true and b is false, i get that but see where a and be and both false the proposition is true ...ahhh i got it you showed that b was true and in both cases of a the proposition was true ....Thanks :)

Comment: @user146167 Yes, it doesn't matter what $a$ is. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note this:
$
((p \land q) \vee r) \rightarrow ((F \land F) \vee T) \rightarrow F\vee T\equiv V\\
(l\vee t) \rightarrow (F \vee T) \equiv T\\
T \Rightarrow T \equiv T 
$

Then $P$ is true.